# Factor language - conversion of integer to string

Tags: factor-lang

I am struggling to convert integer to string in Factor language.

I have tried the below and few more very similar, but unable to find any guideline for Factor language. The only one I have found is this one, but I struggle with it: https://andreaferretti.github.io/factor-tutorial/

```
USING: kernel ;
IN: number-to-string
: number-to-string ( n -- str )
    [ "%d" format ] dip >string ;
```

```
USING: kernel ;
IN: number-to-string
: number-to-string ( n -- str )
    "%d" sprintf ;
```

```
IN: number-to-string
: number-to-string ( n -- str ) >string ;
```

```
USING: strings ;
IN: number-to-string
: number-to-string ( n -- str )
    number>string ;
```

This is the test case I am using

```
USING: number-to-string tools.testest ;
IN: number-to-string.tests

: run-tests ( -- )
  "Fixed tests" describe#{
    "should satisfy fixed tests" it#{
      <{ 67 number-to-string -> "67" }>
    }#
  }#
;

MAIN: run-tests
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find reason why it did not work. This code works. There was missing vocabulary math.parser.

```
USING: math.parser ;

IN: number-to-string

: number-to-string ( n -- str )
  number>string ;
```